# check if $_GET data is thrown into page on document load

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, get

How do I know if a `$_GET` variable has been thrown in my page using jQuery? My `$_GET` variable is:

```
?ok=ok
```

I need to detect if the `$_GET['ok']` is set using jQuery but I don't know how.

Comment: If you have PHP just check with `isset($_GET['ok'])` instead of trying to get url and use a regex to check if it is set/get value with javascript.

Comment: Do you mean that you want to check whether it's present in the URL? Or whether it's been interpreted by PHP?

Comment: @TRiG I want to check if it's present in the url, so I could call a jquery function if it's there.

Comment: So your question has nothing to do with PHP or $_GET. I suggest rewriting and retagging to clarify that.

Comment: @TRiG but is it also possible to detect $_GET using Jquery?

Comment: Do you understand what $_GET is? It's a language construct in PHP: a superglobal variable. It's an automatically generated representation of the query string. What you're interested in in javascript is *the query string itself*, not whatever your server-side language has done with it.

Comment: (Aside: The constant stream of PHP/javascript questions asked by people who have no understanding of the difference between server-side and client-side code is really beginning to bug me.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could just check using PHP if `$_GET['ok']` is set, then echo that into a JavaScript variable:

```
var ok = <?php echo intval(isset($_GET['ok'])) ?>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use the following which was taken from [How to get the value from URL Parameter?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/979995/1700963)

```
var QueryString = function () {
  // This function is anonymous, is executed immediately and 
  // the return value is assigned to QueryString!
  var query_string = {};
  var query = window.location.search.substring(1);
  var vars = query.split("&");
  for (var i=0;i<vars.length;i++) {
    var pair = vars[i].split("=");
    // If first entry with this name
    if (typeof query_string[pair[0]] === "undefined") {
      query_string[pair[0]] = pair[1];
      // If second entry with this name
    } else if (typeof query_string[pair[0]] === "string") {
      var arr = [ query_string[pair[0]], pair[1] ];
      query_string[pair[0]] = arr;
        // If third or later entry with this name
    } else {
      query_string[pair[0]].push(pair[1]);
    }
  } 
  return query_string;
} ();
```

then you can check if $_GET['ok'] is present in url with:

```
if(query_string.ok !== undefined){
    //$_GET['ok'] is in url
}
```